# can't authorise moves through app link

Tags: android, api, authorization

We are developing an app that should get data from the [Moves app API](https://dev.moves-app.com/docs/authentication).

When authorising our app on the mobile phone, we manage to do so successfully in the case in which we submit the PIN provided by the desktop link into the moves app:
`https://api.moves-app.com/oauth/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&scope=<scope>&state=<state>`

In the case where I use the *Mobile website / app* link instead, this won't work:
`moves://app/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&scope=activity%20location&state=<state>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>`

Note: `<redirect_uri>==encodeURIComponent("mymovesconnector:8081/callback")`.

The response we get from the Moves API is 400: `{"error":"invalid_grant"}`.

From the [docs](https://dev.moves-app.com/docs/faq#problems), it says that `invalid_grant` can happen if either:

1. the code in the request is not valid or
2. the code has expired (it’s valid for 5 minutes currently) or
3. the code has been revoked, because it was already used in an access token request (both successful and unsuccessful requests will revoke the code) or
4. you are missing the redirect_uri parameter when it’s required.

My checklist:

1. I guess this could have happened, but how/why should this code, provided over `moves://`, be different than the one provided through the `https://` request? What control do I have over this?
2. not my case, since I'm using the code right away within less then a few seconds
3. if this might have happened, where could it happen other than through the redirect url?
4. I'm providing it always. It's always the same - also in the app settings on moves.

Can't figure out what I'm missing. Went through the docs many times, step by step. No success.

Answer (score 0):

While writing down my question, I managed to figure out a solution to this problem.

The docs don't point out that `response_type=code` might also be used for the `moves://` link. I tried to add this parameter, and it worked!

Note: this has been tested on a virtual android device only (Genymotion).